# How to view all logs with tRPC + Serverless Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, serverless, trpc.io

We recently implemented a backend API that leverages [tRPC v10](https://trpc.io/docs/v10/) and [Serverless Stack](https://sst.dev/). It has been working great, but I just noticed that supplemental logs do not appear in CloudWatch (AWS) after we deploy.

As you can see in the image below, we have a great view of the different invocations and their responses, but we cannot see any other logs that exist within each endpoint. Does tRPC or some combination of settings in Serverless Stack suppress other logs to keep things clean? If so, is there any way to disable that setting and view all logs?

[image: AWS Console]